# Adding slideshow buttons - jquery

Tags: jquery, css, slideshow

I have this very simple slideshow here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/2/
Here's the codes:
HTML:

```
<div id="slideshow">
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5224/5658667829_2bb7d42a9c_m.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://farm6.static.flickr.com/5230/5638093881_a791e4f819_m.jpg">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img src="http://gillespaquette.ca/images/stack-icon.png">
    </div>
</div>
<ul></ul>
```

CSS:

```
#slideshow {
    margin: 50px auto;
    position: relative;
    width: 240px;
    height: 240px;
    padding: 10px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
#slideshow > div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
}

#slideshow img {
    max-width:240px;
    max-height:240px;
}

ul {
    list-style:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
ul li {
    float:left;
    border-radius:10px;
    width:10px;
    height:10px;
    border:1px solid white;
    background:grey;
}
ul li.active {
    background:black;
}
```

Jquery:

```
$("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

var index = 1;
var maxindex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

setInterval(function () {
    $('#slideshow > div:first')
        .fadeOut(1000)
        .next()
        .fadeIn(1000)
        .end()
        .appendTo('#slideshow');
    $('ul li').removeClass('active');
    $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
    index = index < maxindex - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
}, 3000);

for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
    $('ul').append('<li class="' + (i == 0 ? 'active' : '') + '"></li>');
}
```

You can see in the slideshow there's buttons that tells me in which photo I am, I'm trying to relate every button with its photo so when I click it it takes me to its photo, if changing the whole code of the button is needed it will be better because I didn't like my code, I think it's too long.

Comment: when you press any buttons (the circle one "<ul>") it should take me to the photo it's related to.

Comment: please update the question with your problems

Comment: @System-x32z http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/33/ try this out. Let me know if it works for you.

Answer (score 2):

I've also made a fiddle which hopefully does what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/L7s4e/
The main code is as follows:

```
  $("#slideshow > div:gt(0)").hide();

  index = 0;
  maxIndex = $('#slideshow > div').length;

  $mainDiv = $('#slideshow div');
  for (var i = 0; i < maxIndex; i++) {
      var $li = $("<li/>", {
          "data-index": i,
          "class": (i == 0 ? 'active' : '')
      }).on("click",

      function () {
          /* uncomment below if you want slideshow to stop on selection
    to restart call startSlideshow();*/
          //clearInterval(intervalId);
          var imageIndex = $(this).data("index");
          $mainDiv.eq(index).fadeOut(1000);
          $mainDiv.eq(imageIndex).fadeIn(1000);
          index = imageIndex;
          $('ul li').removeClass('active');
          $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
      });

      $('ul').append($li);
  }

  function startSlideshow() {

      intervalId = setInterval(function () {
          $('#slideshow > div').eq(index).fadeOut(1000);
          index = index < maxIndex - 1 ? index + 1 : 0;
          $('#slideshow > div').eq(index).fadeIn(1000);
          $('ul li').removeClass('active');
          $('ul li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('active');
      }, 3000);
  }

  startSlideshow();
```

Hope it works as you wanted.
R.

Answer (score 0):

see following :

```
var $mainDiv  = $('#slideshow div');
for (var i = 0; i < maxindex; i++) {
        var $li = $("<li/>",{"data-index":i, "class":(i == 0 ? 'active' : '')})
                  .on("click",function(){
                        var imageIndex = $(this).data("index");
                        $mainDiv.eq(imageIndex).fadeIn(1000).prev().fadeOut(1000);
                  });

    $('ul').append($li);
}
```

working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/Jtec5/36/

i hope it helps

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work great :/ you can see the styles doesn't switch to the new style as you click it and it mixes the photos with each others, anyway I will up-vote, thank you for giving a try

Comment: see my updated fiddle and the mixing in style happening because of time delay i just change from 3sec to 5sec and it seems ok now. thanks

Comment: still the same problem, try to press the buttons very fast and you can see the photo get mixed